# Как провести валидацию данных модели?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, валидация

Нужно провести валидацию данных в модели (логин/пароль)

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({  
    defaults: {  
        login: "",  
        password: ""  
    },  
    validate: function(attrs){
         var loginRegExp = /^[-a-z-A-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]+(?:\.[-a-z-A-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)*(?:aero|arpa|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|org|pro|tel|travel|[a-z][a-z])$/,
             passwordRegExp = /(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/;
     if (!loginRegExp.test(attrs.login)){
         this.set('login', "");
     }
     if (!passwordRegExp.test(attrs.password)){
         this.set('password', "");
     }}});
```

После передачи данных для проверки

```
model.set({login: "asdasd", password: "33"},{validate: true})
```

проверка происходит (смотрел через дебаггер), однако после прохождения проверки поля модели должны быть пустыми, если данные невалидны, однако данные все равно записываются в поля модели. Никак не пойму почему и как поправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если атрибуты валидны, не возвращайте ничего из validate; если нет, возвращайте любую ошибку на ваш выбор — как просто строку с сообщением, которое надо отобразить, так и сложный объект, программно описывающий ошибку.

[тут немного подробней но суть я думаю вы уловили](http://backbonejs.ru/#Model-validate)